# html <audio> tag play on iPad with a previous user interaction

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, audio

I have a audio tag that only play when a Ajax request return with data.

I know that iPad only play video and audio with a user interaction.

But my Ajax request is made when the user click on a button. So, i have a user interaction.

So, my question is, if there's a way to keep my user interaction "authentication" to play a sound seconds after the user click ?

Comment: make a test page with an ajax call that plays the sound at the end...try it on an ipad and see if it works...I just couldn't tell from your post if you know it DOESN'T work, or if you're just wondering

Comment: Any Video / Audio must have a play clicked. This is not possible. The reason is that Apple has decided against wasting users data. Sorry.

Comment: yes. i tried. actually, my app is ready a month ago. I just trying to adapt some functions to iPad

Comment: Yes Ohgodwhy. I know this. But i have a user interaction that call the ajax. My question is, if is possible to keep the user interaction "auth" to when ajax callback is called.

Comment: What difference would it make? If the user doesn't click on the Audio / Video to start it, nothing matters. There's no work around for this.

Comment: well I have fired audio after drag/drop events on an ipad...so just to be very precise, it's not as if the user clicked an audio play button

Comment: but is a event fired by a user interaction. try to fire the audio inside a setTimeout after a drag/drop

Comment: hey, that was an interesting suggestion. I set the timeout for 1000 milliseconds, and it worked fine. I bumped it to 1001 and it never played. So perhaps you have one second of leeway between action and play

Comment: good point! but sadly my ajax request may take more than 1 second

Comment: it gets even more strange. if I add an input field instead of hardcoding the time, I can make the timeout live quite long (I've tried ten seconds): http://robotwoods.com/dev/misc/so_ipad_audio.html (it's for ipad so it's touch only, not mouse)...I'll see what I can do with ajax

Comment: in my ipad is not play the sound. what is your iOS version and iPad version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15445/discussion-between-robot-woods-and-joao-mosmann)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it works...when the AJAX begins, I start a loop waiting for it to complete. When it does, the loop fires the sound. I have noticed that it doesn't work all the time, I think if the audio hasn't loaded yet, it breaks down (I don't get any errors, but if I wait a few seconds after page load, it seems to be okay)

**EDIT:** While this works for me (iPad2[iOS 5.1.1]) it's not working for the OP (iPad1[iOS4]). Can anyone else share their results? [link](http://robotwoods.com/dev/misc/so_ipad_audio2.html) (and wait a few seconds after load)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>iPad Audio</title>
</head>

<body>
<audio id="noise"><source src="beep.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /></audio>
<button onclick="begin_test();">Go</button>
</body>
<script>
var snd=document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
snd.load();
var shouldPlay=false;

function begin_test(){
    shouldPlay=false;
    play();
    var xmlhttp=((window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            shouldPlay=true;
          }
        } 
        xmlhttp.open("GET","levels.txt",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}

function play(){
    if (shouldPlay){
        snd.play();
        shouldPlay=false;
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(play,10);
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```